# A Revenant's action Fade Pull references The Fade. What is this?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew

In 5e, [the Revenant](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d3/06/ae/d306ae9ba1e59e43d02150519474146a--dnd-classes-dungeons-and-dragons.jpg) has the **Fade Pull** action, emphasis in the middle added:

> ***Fade Pull.*** The revenant targets one creature it can see within 60 feet. The target must make DC 15 Strength saving throw or **be pulled through The Fade** to an unoccupied space beside the revenant, ignoring any obstructions in its path.

What is *The Fade*? Is it some other dimension or plane? What's there?

Comment: May I ask what the source for this is? I do not see this text in the Revenant monster statblock at all, nor is it in the Unearthed Arcana that adds a Revenant playable race.

Comment: @CTWind I've just realised that it might be homebrewed. I was collecting digital resources to print off for ease of use, and must have grabbed an unofficial version by mistake. [The first image here is the one I'm referring to.](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/421719952590779529/)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's very different from the Monster Manual version. Looks like someone's homebrew.

Comment: I would recommend editing the title to "The Revenant's action Fade Pull references The Fade as a place its enemy is pulled through until it occupies the space next to it. What dimension or plane is The Fade?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The homebrew Revenant you have there is fairly obviously Dragon Age-based homebrew. References to the Fade are a strong indicator, but the real clincher is the mention of Marnas Pell.

As for what the Fade *is*, other than almost certainly irrelevant to (and not existing in) your D&D campaign (unless you happen to be playing a Dragon Age-based campaign), it's something like a cross between the Astral Plane and the Ethereal Plane, a spiritual realm that vaguely mirrors the normal world. Further reading [here](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Fade).

Comment: You are absolutely right on this.  I looked at the dragon age wiki and the Revenant there has a skill called Pull and Mass Pull so it makes sense.
http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Revenant

Comment: I always thought of it more as the Shadowfel to be honest or even Xoriat from Eberron given the dream connection.

Answer (score 2):

I looked and there is no mention of The Fade that I could find. But the homebrew it likely comes from resembles the Shadowfell.

The Shadowfell, sometimes simply called Shadow, was a parallel plane from which necrotic energies and shadow magic stemmed. It existed as sort of a counterpart to the Feywild in the sense that it was a reflection or "echo" of the Prime Material Plane except that it was a bleak, desolate place full of decay and death.

History
The Shadowfell was created in 1385 DR when Shar, having successfully arranged Mystra's death, bound the energies of the Negative Energy Plane with the Plane of Shadow.

Inhabitants 
Much of the Shadowfell was a twisted reflection of the Prime Material plane and was populated primarily by dead creatures such as ghosts, specters, and other undead who for whatever reason refused to leave the Shadowfell and continue on to the Fugue Plane. There were however, numerous other inhabitants, such as communities of shadar-kai, Shadovar, and dark ones.

↑ 2.0 2.1 2.2 Bruce R. Cordell, Ed Greenwood, Chris Sims (August 2008). Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide. (Wizards of the Coast), p. 69. ISBN 978-0-7869-4924-3.

Comment: While the other answer is correct, I appreciate this one a lot since it gives me some good stuff to use. My player went through The Fade, and I said I'd get back to him on what he saw there. Thank you for this description :)